# How do you stream an online game without getting lag in the process?

Tags: performance, streaming, obs

When I try to record for [twitch](http://www.twitch.tv/) (using [Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com/)) I get a higher ping than the usual, when people out there doesn't experience any difficulties.

Is there some trick behind it, or is my internet so bad? Do I have to use an additional device than just the software or something?

**EDIT 28/01** this is my diagnostic result:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Streaming lag might come from different sources.

1. Processing lag. The video encoding takes to much resources on your computer, monopolises CPU or disk Input Output.
2. Uploading lag. The video takes to much size and reach the upload limit of your connection.

The second is most likely to create high pings.

To reduce the effect of 2. you need to compress more, requiring more processing power and might increase 1. This can be done by tuning the codec settings (encoding profiles and such).

The only way to reduce 1. and 2. at the same time is to downscale the video, or reduce the number of frame per seconds recorded. This will reduce the quantity of information to encode and therefore the necessary size to transmit. Obviously the quality of the stream will decrease as well, but you can't get all at the same time.

Another way to get better streaming quality would be increasing your processing power (CPU, disk speed, GPU maybe) and your connection bandwidth.

Edit: Tip, if you have NVidia Graphic Card of good quality, there is the opportunity to use NVEnc as your encoder, this uses the GPU to process encode the video, and provides a huge improvement in performance, since the card already processes some of it for display already. It will also lighten the charge of the CPU.

Comment: When I stream, game works perfectly: FPS goes normal and the OBS still runs fluently, also I don't notice any high ping in-game. But when I go to twitch, the sound works perfectly, but it looks really choppy (image freezes very often).

Comment: OBS shows an indicator on the bottom. If red, it means your connection is not sufficient enough to handle the stream. If it's green, maybe you should check in the encoding side. Configuration of streaming is really difficult. If you'd like, look me up on google+ and send me a message. I can certainly share my configuration with you. Not sure it would help, but I know it's working for me.

Comment: I updated my question including a speed test as the **[estimator](https://www.obsproject.com/estimator)** said, not sure if this estimator tool is accurate though.

Answer (score 5):

To put it simply, you're always going to get **some** kind of lag when you're streaming. Ping, in this case, is not directly affected; it's influenced by your remaining bandwidth while you're streaming.

How much lag depends on your upload speed and your stream's bitrate. For example, I have a 1 Mbit/s upload speed, and everyone in my house suffers when I'm trying to upload a YouTube video because uploading files always uses as much bandwidth as possible (by default).

Streaming, on the other hand, is first encoded by either *variable bitrate* (VBR) or *constant bitrate* (CBR). In variable bitrate, you're selecting a quality (from a range of numbers) or constraining the bitrate by a maximum and minimum. This works when the stream doesn't need all of the bandwidth, but if you're moving around a lot, then your stream's quality will suffer greatly. In constant bitrate, you're just telling the encoder what bitrate you want. That's it. The bitrate is more stable, and the encoder will take advantage of any bandwidth left over (thus increasing quality, but be aware that some of those bits are actually stuffed ones). But back to the question.

You'll want to set the encoder for OBS to CBR and lower your bitrate so that it's about two-thirds or three-fourths your upload speed. I'd set it between 512 Kbps to 768 Kbps in my case. That way, your game will have plenty of bandwidth left over to send packets to the server and download player states back to you.

*(I'm not exactly sure how ISPs bottleneck download and upload speeds, but I'm guessing that your download and upload are summed together and throttled down if needed.)*

Answer (score 2):

A couple other options not mentioned.

1) If you have an nVidia card, use their Shadowplay utility instead of OBS.  It encodes using the video card hardware and streams directly to Twitch, and will probably improve your performance.

2) If your router supports it, turn on QoS (Quality of Service).  Set it up so the stream to Twitch is placed at the lowest priority, and possibly a capped upload rate.

Comment: OBS also supports hardware recording. You only have to choose NVENC instead of x264.

Answer (score 1):

You've got ever so slightly better internet than myself. I've got 12Meg down, but only 700k up.

Anyway, the good news, is you can stream. The bad news, is realistically, only at a very poor resolution realistically.

Go onto youtube, and set the resolution to 360p. That is honestly about as good as you'll get it. It's to do with how many bits need to go up the pipe to twitch. You also need to set the max encoding bitrate to about 75% of your available upstream. So in your case, you could get away with 700kbps. (Maybe even as high as 850kbps without affecting game performance, your mileage may vary)

A worthwhile OBC calculator is [here](https://obsproject.com/estimator). It'll give you some suggested settings based on what you enter.

Good luck with it!

Comment: The OBC calculator link is a nice touch. However the "I got X kbps" part is unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

Your download speed does not matter. But I will tell you this 10mb download speed is not good for online gaming in the first place. So I would say first at hand would be to change your plan to 25mb download speed to begin with. Second if your having problems set your bit rate at 15 whether your using obs or xsplit. 3rd trying to stream with 1.08 upload speed is not going to work. I mean it will work but not well. To get good effect on your stream you need to be running 20mb or higher download speed for your actual gameplay. And 5mb upload speed for your stream. I hope this helps.

Comment: What ? What do you mean by "10mb" is it 10 mbps or 10MB/s ? Because the first one is kinda average for most of the World and the later is way way above top speeds in most places ...